# E421: Getting color name not recognized in perfectly valid statement

Tags: colors, hex, vim

I want to change the colors of my parentheses colorized with [Better Rainbow Parentheses](https://github.com/kien/rainbow_parentheses.vim).

The colors are specified like this:

```
let g:rbpt_colorpairs = [
    \ ['brown',       'RoyalBlue3'],
    \ ['Darkblue',    'SeaGreen3'],
    \ ['darkgray',    'DarkOrchid3'],
    \ ['darkgreen',   'firebrick3'],
    \ ['darkcyan',    'RoyalBlue3'],
    \ ['darkred',     'SeaGreen3'],
    \ ['darkmagenta', 'DarkOrchid3'],
    …
    \ ]
```

The function changing the colors in the plugin is this:

```
func! rainbow_parentheses#toggle()
    if !exists('s:active')
        cal rainbow_parentheses#load(0)
    endif
    let afunc = exists('s:active') && s:active ? 'clear' : 'activate'
    cal call('rainbow_parentheses#'.afunc, [])
endfunc
```

Since I’m using Solarized I want specific hex colors, so I got this:

```
let g:rbpt_colorpairs = [
    \ ['yellow',    '#b58900'],
    \ ['orange',       '#cb4b16'],
    \ ['red',    '#dc322f'],
    \ ['magenta',   '#d33682'],
    \ ['violet',    '#6c71c4'],
    \ ['blue',     '#268bd2'],
    \ ['cyan', '#2aa198'],
    …
    \ ]
```

Yet, on restart and turning the plugin on, I get this error multiple times:

```
E421: Color name or number not recognized: cterm=orange guifg=#cb4b16
```

Even better, doing the :exe done in the function manually works like a charm, like:

```
:exe 'hi default level4c ctermfg=orange guifg=#cb4b16'
```

Even with concatenation it works:

```
:let foo = '#cb4b16
:exe 'hi default level4c ctermfg=orange guifg='.foo
```

What could be wrong?!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is not in the GUI RGB color, it's in the `cterm=orange` definition.

See `:help cterm-colors` for recognized values; `orange` is not one of them.

Comment: Excuse me while I go hit myself. Fun fact: I once had the problem with terminal colors and orange in the past already. I should sometimes learn to learn from my mistakes. :)

Comment: Although, one question remains: Why did vim not complain when I used it as a command?!

Comment: So how can I set a color if I know its name?

Comment: For anybody else, there is a table matching colors to their vim numbers: http://www.calmar.ws/vim/256-xterm-24bit-rgb-color-chart.html

Answer (score 0):

```
function! Gfagivesorange()
         colors morning
         hi Spellbad   term=standout cterm=bold ctermfg=Red ctermbg=White
         hi Spellbad   term=standout cterm=NONE ctermfg=Orange ctermbg=White
         call Myhi()
endfunc
```

This function will give you Orange (red which is not Bold). It is a NCURSES thing, but people aren't mastering or knowing NCURSES (not many of informaticians).